# Generate datetimes for particular format for future years

Tags: python, datetime, sklearn-pandas

I would like to generate a sequential series of years between two given year with 3 hrs of intervals. For example in the following format  `year  Month  Day hour 
                                  1992    1     1   0
                                  1992    1     1   3`

How can I generate time series for the next 15 year in the above format?

I have written code so far this

```
import datetime
start = datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 15, 0, 0, 0)
end = datetime.datetime(2008, 8, 22, 0, 0, 0)

delta = end - start

for i in range(delta.days + 1):
    print start + datetime.timedelta(days=i)
```

But did not getting an idea after this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you included `pandas` in your tags, allow me to provide a solution with `pandas`. Pardon the random dates.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.date_range(start='2008-8-15', end='2010-8-15', freq='3h')[:10]
```

```
Out[89]: 
DatetimeIndex(['2008-08-15 00:00:00', '2008-08-15 03:00:00',
               '2008-08-15 06:00:00', '2008-08-15 09:00:00',
               '2008-08-15 12:00:00', '2008-08-15 15:00:00',
               '2008-08-15 18:00:00', '2008-08-15 21:00:00',
               '2008-08-16 00:00:00', '2008-08-16 03:00:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='3H')
```

With respects to your example:

```
import pandas as pd

dates = pd.date_range(start='2008-8-15', end='2010-8-15', freq='3h')

pd.DataFrame([dates.year, dates.month, dates.day, dates.hour], index=['year',
                                       'month', 'day', 'hour']).T
```

```
Out[98]: 
      year  month  day  hour
0     2008      8   15     0
1     2008      8   15     3
2     2008      8   15     6
3     2008      8   15     9
4     2008      8   15    12
    ...    ...  ...   ...
5836  2010      8   14    12
5837  2010      8   14    15
5838  2010      8   14    18
5839  2010      8   14    21
5840  2010      8   15     0
[5841 rows x 4 columns]
```

Comment: Perfect. Thanks, Nicolas. Just one question. instead of giving from and to year; Can I generate the next 20 years of time series of the same format just giving starting year?

Comment: Yes you can. You can specify the number of `periods`, for instance 20 years divided in 3hrs. `dates = pd.date_range(start='2008-8-15', periods=(24/3)*365*20, freq='3h')`